# Julia - Genie Dashboard Table not displaying data

Tags: julia, dashboard, genie.jl

I'm new to Genie (and Julia) and I'm trying to make a basic dashboard on video game data, but am having some issues displaying my data.

I have my app as:

```
module App
using CSV
using DataFrames
using GenieFramework
@genietools

# dataset
const data = CSV.File("data/games_cleaned.csv") |> DataFrame
println(data)
# add your data analysis code
@handlers begin
    @in number_of_games = 10
    @out datatable = DataTable(data)
    @out datatable_paginated = DataTablePagination(rows_per_page=50)
    @out barplot = PlotData[]
end

# register a new route and the page that will begin
# loaded on access
@page("/", "app.jl.html")
end
```

Using the Genie Builder and trying to display data in a table in the no code editor, the table comes up saying "No data available". Has anyone else encountered this problem and knows a fix? Cheers!

Comment: late reponse, but in general when using a builder you need to bind/connect data and columns; for data will be data.data, for columns columns.data; that should help